# Android Studio not launching an emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

When i am trying to run Android code in Android Studio it shows the following in the event log. But I'm not getting any output and am unable to open the emulator.

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug, :app:assembleDebugAndroidTest]
7:28:43 PM Gradle build finished in 4s 386ms
7:30:24 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
7:30:27 PM Gradle build finished in 3s 576ms
```

When I am trying to run from AVD Manager it shows as follows:

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
>   Output:
>   emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 384MB
>   emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
>   emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
>   CPU acceleration status: Android Emulator requires an Intel processor with VT-x and NX support.
>   Your CPU: 'AuthenticAMD'

Comment: have you tried running emulator from the AVD panel?

Comment: When i am trying to run from avd manager it shows as follows. Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 384MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: Android Emulator requires an Intel processor with VT-x and NX support.  Your CPU: 'AuthenticAMD'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this type of problem happens, best way is to make sure you have followed below points correctly.

- You have proper SDK installed
- You have Intel HAXM & virtualization option enabled in your BIOS
- Configure emulator correctly, download the Intel X86 Atom system image for better performance.
- User arm instead of x86 if you have AMD processor when creating emulator.(In most of case)

Answer (score 1):

When you created your device you should have used arm instead of x86. It must work

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [Visual Studios Android Emulator](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx)

It is stand-alone, so you dont need Visual Studio to run it, it boots up in seconds, and is more robust then [GenyMotions](https://www.genymotion.com/) Android Emulator.

Launch your emulator from VS Android emulator, once the OS boots and the homescreen displays run your code and it will give you an option to choose the VS emulator in android studio.

Answer (score 1):

Download latest version of Haxm and enable it in bios (hardware acceleration), on most computers it is basically turned off